# Transfer from Dubai T3 to Lucknow flight(flydubai) T2

Tags: transit, dubai

I'm in an Indian Citizen and  will be arriving from Houston,USA to dubai EK-212 flight and then have a connecting flight from Dubai to Lucknow,India EK-2126 managed by fly dubai 10 hours after landing in Dubai. I shall be staying in Dubai international hotel for those 10 hours and then catch the Lucknow flight at terminal 2.

My question is do I need to take any kind of transit visa for this as I would be in Dubai hotel for 10 hours and then have a connecting flight to catch from T2.

Also, how far is T2 from International hotel?

Which Concourse A,B, or C I should stay in hotel which is nearest to T2?

Appreciate your inputs here.

Comment: You will get transit visa on arrival based on your USA visa

Answer (score 1):

There is an airside transit bus between T3 and T2, so you can transfer between your Emirates and flydubai flights without passing immigration or requiring a transit visa. The bus leaves from Concourse A apron level. Any Emirates staff in terminal 3 can help you find it if necessary.

If you didn't happen to arrive at an A gate, there are also airside buses that will take you to concourse A.

If you would like to leave the airport during your layover, you can apply for a transit visa via Emirates by going to [Manage your booking](https://www.emirates.com/english/manage-booking/).